# DevExpress XtraReport Text Being Cut Off Between Two Pages

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a DexExpress XtraReport that has many labels in each row, however, if i have more than 14 rows shown on the report, it will split onto the next page. The text of the labels will then also split to next page as follow:

Page 1:
[image]

Page 2:
[image]

As you can see, the last row in Page 1 has split into two, showing the top part of the text on page 1 but bottom part of the text is on page 2.

I have tried to set the Label.KeepTogether property to True but it doesnt solve my issue. I have also tried to set HorizontalContentSplitting to Smart which also didn't solve the issue.

Thank you for your response!

Comment: put page braker from extra report

Comment: There is a page breaker tool in the xtrareport you can use this to brak the page

Comment: Also there is a shirk tool in the properties of the page put it true.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried to add a Page Breaker but it didn't solve the problem too. Another details that I would like to add is the label is set CanGrow Property to True and Multiline to False. Will is affect the outsome of Report? @JojiThomasEapen

Comment: use XRRichTextBox instead of label. and put page breaker

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `Label.KeepTogether` property to true, I suggest setting the whole band (I presume detail band) `KeepTogether` property to true.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is Your report layout contains labels?
I think the text will be cut off only when using the "rich" text.
may be you can replace the rich text by the simple labels?